# How to organize the DB result collection as hierarchy?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table in the db which has columns of the structure of the organization:

| id | group | branch | unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | g1 | b1 | null |
| 2 | g1 | b1 | u2 |
| 3 | g2 | null | u3 |
| 4 | g2 | b6 | u4 |
| 5 | g3 | b7 | u5 |

And as seen in the example data above, not all the levels have data so some are null.

I want to get all the possible combinations of hierarchies so I fetch the data using `GROUP BY`:

```
$data = Table::select('group', 'branch', 'unit')->groupBy('group', 'branch', 'unit')->get();
```

This returns the result as separated rows.

But how can I make it into an hierarchy array, for example:

```
[ 
    "g1" => ["b1" => ["other", "u2"]]
    "g2" => ["b6" => ["u4"], "other" => ["u3"]]
    "g3" => ["b7" => ["other", "u5"]]
]
```

I replaced `null` with `other` in this case for better reference

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Laravel developer, so I can't say if there's a built-in way to do this, but in general PHP it isn't that complicated.

I personally like to back my things with object whenever they reach a certain level of complexity, so the way that I normally solve this is to represent the Group, Branch and Unit as classes, the first two with children, and then a main array to hold all of the groups. I also store groups and children with the object's "name" or "identifier" as an index in the array to make it easier to look things up. Then it is just a matter of looping.

You can optionally move the `isset` logic into the classes themselves with an `addBranch` method on the group, or something like that, but it mostly works out the same.

```php
Class Unit{
    public function __construct(public readonly ?string $name){}
}

Class Branch{
    public array $units = [];
    public function __construct(public readonly ?string $name){}
}

Class Group{
    public array $branches = [];
    public function __construct(public readonly string $name){}
}

$sampleData = [
    ['g1', 'b1',   null],
    ['g1', 'b1',   'u2'],
    ['g2', null,   'u3'],
    ['g2', 'b6',   'u4'],
    ['g3', 'b7',   'u5'],
];

$groups = [];
foreach($sampleData as $row){
    $groupId  = $row[0];
    $branchId = $row[1];
    $unitId   = $row[2];
    
    if(!isset($groups[$groupId])){
        $groups[$groupId] = new Group($groupId);
    }
    
    if(!isset($groups[$groupId]->branches[$branchId])){
        $groups[$groupId]->branches[$branchId] = new Branch($branchId);
    }
    
    if(!isset($groups[$groupId]->branches[$branchId]->units[$unitId])){
        $groups[$groupId]->branches[$branchId]->units[$unitId] = new Unit($unitId);
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/WE17l#v8.1.13

Answer (score 2):

You can use the collection `groupBy()` method "twice" to reach that result (1 + number of groups since it's in a loop).

```
$data = Table::select('group', 'branch', 'unit')->groupBy('group', 'branch', 'unit')->get();

$data = $data->groupBy('group');
$data = $data->map(function($group){
    return $group->groupBy('branch');
});
```

Here is an [example](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/15820331-2cd1-42c1-b239-a4b13d74c50b)

You can also do a simple loop to generate the result in an array. Autovivification will do its magic.

```
$data = Table::select('group', 'branch', 'unit')->groupBy('group', 'branch', 'unit')->get();

$groups = [];
foreach($data as $row){
    $groups[$row->group][$row->branch][] = $row->unit;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2FYsV)

Comment: Great answer! I always forget that autovivification exists

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you for reminding me of the technical term.

Comment: @N69S thank you, that's really good and works. But I tried it on a similar table I also need it for which has 4 hierarchies, like `subunit`, but when I try to add another level of mapping, something goes wrong - suddenly the inner levels all become grouped by empty string (`""`): https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/cf55e53f-333d-4d09-a6f3-11603749f407. Do you know why?

Comment: @Stackerito here is the example with subunit. https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/4023c0d4-bf67-4663-af56-62a279f10aea

Comment: @Stackerito the single loop solution (without collection) is a much performant one with n complexity `$groups[$row->group][$row->branch][$row->unit][] = $row->subunit;`